# Compatibility issues of Jquery with CSS media queries?

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm running into instances where CSS media queries, for instance for smaller devices (smartphones), run fine on my page for styling initial page elements, but then apply inconsistently on elements that I'm later inserting into the page using Jquery methods. After testing this a lot – looking for whether I made a mistake with an overriding CSS class or something of the kind – I can't find a solution, prompting me to wonder whether the problem is within Jquery itself, perhaps because some Jquery methods are not so compatible with CSS media queries as others???

Here's some of the html from the page that styles as intended:

```
<div class="headingwrapper top-center">
    <h1 class="bigheading">Site Title</h1>
    <h4 class="tagline">My cool tagline</h4>
</div>
```

On clicking a “start tour” button, these functions run, among others:

```
$('#newbgimage').fadeIn(2000);
$(".headingwrapper").html('<h2 class="tourtext-white">We\'re beginning the tour...</h2>').fadeIn(500);
```

From the media queries stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {  .tourtext-white {font-size: 1.8rem;} }
```

From the main stylesheet:  `.tourtext-white { font-size: 4.3rem; }`

Here on smartphones the browser accepts the media query and renders the smaller font.

Later in my tour, however, html elements that I have inserted using Jquery do not always render according to the CSS media queries applied to them. For example:

```
$("body").append('<div class="headingwrapper-left"><h5>A new tour page heading</h5></div>');
```

Main stylesheet:

`.headingwrapper-left h5 { color: teal; };`

Media queries stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { .headingwrapper-left h5 { color: red; }}
```

The text in smartphones of this size still appears teal, not red as intended. The same is still true if I use the .after() or .before() methods to add my new html rather than $('body').append().

Anyone struggled with something similar before?

Comment: Side note, you should escape a quote from `We're beginning the tour` to `We\'re beginning the tour`.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets cascade, so first - make sure red isn't down from teal somewhere in your stylesheet calls. If it still doesn't work - and you should really avoid these, but adding an !important to the teal color may shock it into working.

Comment: Good thought, but that doesn't address it. The stylesheet cascade is alright, global styles first, then media queries, and !important is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

320px should be the minimum width.  What device has less than 320px?  Your media query should start at 320.  Try something like:
media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px)  { .headingwrapper-left h5 { color: red; }}